# [Python]: Check that no *args. is passed

Tags: python

Say that I have a function with this signature `foo(*args,a:int=0, b:int=1)`.

How to check if no `*args` is passed?
I am trying

```
def foo(*args,a:int=0, b:int=1):
    if args is None:
       print("No args passed")
```

If I call it with `foo()`, but I don't get anything printed on screen.

Comment: `args` won't be `None`, it will be an *empty tuple*.

Comment: Did you mean: `if not args:`?

Comment: That would work.

Comment: You have been very quick in replying :D `if not args` work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In conclusion:
Use `not args` or `args == ()`

```
def foo(*args, a:int=0, b:int=1):
    if not args:
       print("No args passed")
foo()
```

```
def foo(*args, a:int=0, b:int=1):
    if args == ():
       print("No args passed")
foo()
```